# Pass values to Custom fields of DocuSign Template

Tags: docusignapi

I have developed an app in Golang. At the end of the process the visitor clicks the button "Sign and Submit". After clicking the button, the Docusign template opens (called via API). The user signs the document and it's closed.

Is there a possibility to pass the values of fields from my app to the custom fields on Docusign template?

Comment: Please do not revert good edits made to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add custom fields to the envelope via this Rest API Endpoint ["Custom Fields"](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Add%20Envelope%20Custom%20Fields%20to%20an%20Envelope.htm)